# Can I write a bash script and add it into right-click list of the graphical file explorer?

Tags: scripts, ssh, nautilus, context-menu

I am sort of new to Ubuntu/UNIX. I frequently need to use an ssh terminal over a device that I also mount via sshfs.

I was wondering if it's possible to write a bash script like this, and have it listed on my right click menu as "Open SSH-Terminal in Remote Folder":

```
if right-clicked on remote_sshfs_folder:
     do:
        calculate relative path to the remote user.
        open a new terminal in the host,
        run: ssh remote-user@remote_device ; cd calculated/relative/path
```

**Solved:** By the guidance I got from the answer below, I started to look into the matter and I was able to implement exactly what I wanted.

Comment: What right-click menu? In Files?

Comment: In the file explorer yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. The file manager Files (nautilus) has a feature "nautilus scripts". When this folder exists and contains executable scripts, a "Scripts" entry will appear in the right-click menu that will include these scripts. See the [Ubuntu Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto) to see how you can use predefined variables containing the selected file names, the current directory, etc.

Comment: This helps a lot, thanks! Perhaps covering almost everything I needed.